# How do I mount internal HDDs in Ubuntu via the command line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, mount

I'm new to Linux and have a home server set up running Ubuntu.

In the GUI it's very easy to mount my additional internal hard drives. I just double click on them. Since I have made this server headless, I now need to mount via the command line.

How can I replicate the very simple double click GUI behavior?

So far all the information I've found is very complex. Ubuntu auto generated folders for each hdd under `/media` and I can see the hard drives under `/dev` but have no idea which is which, as the hardware is identical between them. I also don't know how they are formated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Need to check your new hard drive is mounted as `sdb` or `hdb` and you can do it by using

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
```

Lets say your hard drive is mounted as `sdb1`.

You need to create a mount point using the mkdir command. This will be the location from which you will access the `/dev/sdb1` drive.

```
$ sudo mkdir /media/newhd
```

To mount the drive, enter:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/newhd
$ df -H
```

To view files `cd` to `/media/newhd`, enter:

```
$ cd /media/newhd
$ ls -l
```

Comment: I think you've used numeric 1. It would be lowercase 'l' (for list)

Comment: -l returns nothing